Using TG_TABLE_NAME in postgresql trigger function in a SELECT query
I have this plpgsql trigger function

DECLARE
    prev_record daily_data%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO prev_record
    FROM ONLY TG_TABLE_NAME
    WHERE base = NEW.quote AND quote = 'USDT'
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1;
    
    IF EXISTS prev_record THEN
        NEW.volume_usd := NEW.volume * prev_record.close;
    END IF;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;

The main motive of this function is to grab the latest value from a table and use that to update the volume_usd of the new value being inserted.
This function is going to be used in many tables thus I used TG_TABLE_NAME in the select statement but it seems to throw error.
ERROR:  relation "tg_table_name" does not exist at character 41
2024-06-06 16:32:57.222 UTC [3253] QUERY:  SELECT *                      FROM ONLY TG_TABLE_NAME
             WHERE base = NEW.quote AND quote = 'USDT'
             ORDER BY timestamp DESC
             LIMIT 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_volume_usd() line 5 at SQL statement

I have looked at execute function but don't think it would be useful here as I would require storing that
Edit:
I have tried using EXECUTE but it doesn't work
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_volume_usd()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    prev_record daily_data%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('
        SELECT * INTO prev_record
        FROM ONLY %I
        WHERE base = $1 AND quote = ''USDT''
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ', TG_TABLE_NAME) USING NEW.quote;
    
    IF EXISTS prev_record THEN
        NEW.volume_usd := NEW.volume * prev_record.close;
    END IF;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;

ERROR:
ERROR:  EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO is not implemented
HINT:  You might want to use EXECUTE ... INTO or EXECUTE CREATE TABLE ... AS instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_volume_usd() line 4 at EXECUTE 

SQL state: 0A000

datatype of prev_record.close is NUMERIC

Please (always) post the complete CREATE FUNCTION statement, not just the body. And show one CREATE TRIGGER statement to go with it. And what's the data type of prev_record.close?

I have edited the question to include them.

You missed the CREATE TRIGGER statement. I am going to assume BEFORE triggers.

Generally, identifiers (including table names) cannot be parameterized in plain SQL. You need dynamic SQL with EXECUTE for that.
Also, IF EXISTS prev_record THEN isn't valid syntax. IF FOUND ... would work in its place.
But the logic of this trigger falls apart under concurrent write load. Multiple concurrent transactions will compute incoherent values due to visibility issues. Either use the isolation level SERIALIZABLE, or don't try this magic trick at all and store plain values and do computations across the time series in a query / view / materialized view instead.
That said, here is a valid function definition:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_volume_usd()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _prev_close numeric;  -- we only need this column
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
      $q$
      SELECT close
      FROM   ONLY %I
      WHERE  base = $1        -- compare base to NEW.quote?
      AND    quote = 'USDT'
      ORDER  BY timestamp DESC  -- must be defined NOT NULL !
      LIMIT  1
      $q$, TG_TABLE_NAME)
   USING NEW.quote
   INTO  _prev_close;
   
   IF _prev_close IS NOT NULL THEN
      NEW.volume_usd := NEW.volume * _prev_close;
   END IF;
   
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

Must be used in a BEFORE trigger.
With EXECUTE, the INTO clause can't be nested in the dynamic query, it has to be appended to the EXECUTE command like demonstrated. Details in the manual.
After switching to dynamic SQL, my initial advice to use FOUND is void. The manual:

Note in particular that EXECUTE changes the output of GET DIAGNOSTICS, but does not change FOUND.

In this case, we can also check _prev_close IS NOT NULL - assuming the column is defined NOT NULL.

My EXECUTE implementation doesn't work error and code provided above. The concurrency issue is also taken care in the insertion side

quote and base are generated columns, are they expected to cause problems?

Also most of the target tables for this function has another function which modifies the NEW (Both BEFORE) will that also be a problem?

The manual: "Stored generated columns are computed after BEFORE triggers and before AFTER triggers." This is a trigger function is for a BEFORE trigger (which you didn't disclose), so yes, that won't work. You need to do more. But that was never part of the question.

Multiple triggers on the exact same event are fired in alphabetical order (of the trigger name, not the function name!)
